# Filtering data before applying update with scala-js-d3

Tags: scala, d3.js, scala.js

I am using [scala-js-d3](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3) to draw some rather complicated graphs. For performance reasons I want to filter the update set before applying transformations.

My code so far looks like this:

```
def showData(a: Drawable): Boolean = // [...] determines if the data point should be visible

val selection: Update[Drawable] =
      d3.select(s"#$parentElement")
        .selectAll(s".$className")
        .data(drawables.toJSArray, (a: Drawable) => a.id.toString)

selection.enter
  .append("g")
   // [...] drawing of the data point

selection
  .attr("display", (a: Drawable)  => if(showData(a)) "block" else "hidden") // (*2)

selection
  .filter((a: Drawable)  => showData(a)) // This is not possible? (*1)
  .transition()
  .duration(600)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("transform", (a: Drawable) => /* [...] */)
```

Is there any way to filter the data to update before applying the transformations like shown in `(*1)`? Most of these data points are invisible anyway so it does not make sense to apply these transformations.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** The filtering cannot be made during the `select` part because then the change from visible to invisible (see `(*2)`) would never happen.

Comment: suggestion to your code: `def showData(a: Drawable) = if(a.visible) true else false` can you write `def showData(a: Drawable) = a.visible`

Comment: Ah yes, sure. This is not the real code anyway, just something I wrote real quick to demonstrate the problem I have.

Comment: just by the code I would guess the filtering should be made in the `select` part

Comment: Good point, but unfortunately I think that is not possible in my case (I updated my question).